# Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock()->toHtml() taking much load time

Tags: blocks, template, render, render-blocking

I am calling a block method of another module in one of the .phtml file using below code--

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('tablisting/list')->toHtml();
```

this code works but it takes too much time in loading (**approx.- 12 sec**).
When I dig it deeper I found **toHtml()** function which calling  **$this->renderView()** in **Mage_Core_Block_Template** file. This line of code taking much time in loading.

Block file **List.php** -

```
protected function _toHtml(){
        if(!$this->getConfig('isenabled')) return;
        $is_ajax = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('is_ajax');
        if( $is_ajax ){
            $cat_id    = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('tab_cat_id');
            $order_id  = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
            $type      = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('data_type');
            if( $type == 'order' ){
                $child_items = $this->getProductsOrder($order_id);
            } else {
                $child_items = $this->getProducts($cat_id);
            }
            $template_file = 'sm/tablisting/default_items.phtml';
        }else{
            $template_file = 'sm/tablisting/default.phtml';
        }
        $this->setTemplate($template_file);
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

Is there any other way to call that block method in my template file ?
How can reduce loading time ? Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please give a link to the module's source? If you bought the module, I think it's better to contact the module's developer to get support. In the code you provided, there's nothing that takes any time.

Comment: I would recommend turning on the Profiler see. http://inchoo.net/magento/keeping-your-magento-fit-with-built-in-profiler/ or maybe trying out the AOE_Profiler https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler this will give you more details as what part of your custom code is taking so much of the time and resources.

Comment: I see that the variable `$child_items` maybe that's the one that takes a lot of time (most likely the code is not the best code)

Answer (score 2):

You need to optimize code in your custom block in this case. In whatever way you are going to include your block in your layout, it will eventually call `Mage_Core_Block_Template::renderView()` and will take time to render it.

Content of block `tablisting/list` is what makes problem here. From the type name, I believe you have a collection associated with that block and most probably this collection is what makes problem here.

We cannot give a specific solution in this situation unless we see your block code.

### Edit

Your edit is not enough to give you a proper solution. I recommend you to use profiler tool in Magento to debug such issues. You can try ***[Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler)*** module for better results.

Comment: Hello @Rajeev..I have a large block file to copy/paste here. Although I have edited my question with the methods which is being called. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @shashank please see my edit. Update is not give clue of real problem. You may need to use profiler tool of magento to find out the culprit.